# Where shall I call wp_register_script() to load js in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[This](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321) article explains very clearly how to load javascript file in wordpress, expect for one thing. Where do I call wp_register_script()? So many php file, where should I put it? 
Where should I put my js file? 
Can I just use script tag in text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to add your javascript files on your theme and lets also assume that you want to add a javascript file called `custom-script.js`. In that case you can create a folder called `js` in your theme folder and add your js file on that folder. Then you add the following code  in your **functions.php** file of the theme.

```
function wptuts_scripts_basic()
{    
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_basic' );
```